# How to replace just close minimize window icons?

Tags: icons, minimize

I don't like those gray minimize maximize buttons (icons). How can I replace just them. I do not want to install a new theme just the buttons in standart elementary theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the elementary theme and replace the icon files and set it as a new theme.

**Edit:**

Sorry i was on my iPod so i couldn't really tell you in all details.

1. Copy the elementary theme from /usr/share/icons/ to documents.
2. Open the index.theme and edit the following.

> [Icon Theme] Name=elementary

To

> [Icon Theme] Name=elementaryNewTheme

3. Change the folder to the same name.
4. Get the icons you would like to replace and replace the ones in the "elementaryNewTheme" folder. (you can use the search option of pantheon-files to make it easier)
5. Open pantheon with administrator (right click at the dock -> new window as admin)
6. now copy the "elementaryNewTheme" from /home/yourUserName/Documents/ to /usr/share/icons/
7. use elementary tweaks to change the icon pack to "elementaryNewTheme"
8. should do the trick.

Comment: aha ... that easy? Why you even answered?

Comment: i edited my answer.